# Is there a way to namespace a PORO class without a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my press_post/updater.rb file

```
class PressPost::Updater
  def say_something
    p 'hello world'
  end
end
```

But when I run things I get this
    ': uninitialized constant PressPost (NameError)

I know that other answers have touched around this.. 
One went so far as to make an empty module inside the class file on the first line.. That seems flawed.

I know there is a way to not have to do this extra code.  I believe it's a config or something, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Note.. I want to do this because these are in a sub directory and it is a whole lot easier searching the code for PressPost::Updater than Updater

Comment: See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#nesting and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#nesting-and-qualified-constants.

Answer (score -1):

Not if this is what you are after but I would always wrap the class into a module:

```
module PressPost
  class Updater
    def say_something
      p 'hello world'
    end
  end
end
```

This is not entirely equivalent to your current code as someone points [out in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7821792/564721) but it’s cleaner which I guess is what you are after.

Comment: Would you wrap every one of the classes in the folder in modules?  I don't like having to wrap everything in a module.. makes searching for the class definition of PressPost::Updater.new objects a PITA.

Comment: @baash05 If you don't get a better answer, `ack --files-with-matches Updater` will at least tell you what files/paths contain your class, so you can scope your search further.